# Reading from file. create a variable with the name Java

Tags: java

Okay, Im working on a project that requires me to save a large volume of files. in the format .dat with information that the variable stores stored inside the file. Is there a way in Java 1.7 to create a variable with the name that it reads from file? If not what would be the best way to create an ever growing number of variables? Im at a bit of a loss, I don't know of a way to do what i need... Dpes anyone have any advice?

Comment: Dynamic variables names are not possible in Java. Use an array, `List` or `Map`.

Comment: In short words, Collection is your question's answer. Google it.

Comment: Why would you need a variable with a given name at runtime - its not like you can do extra manipulations? For an ever growing number of variables, as the others said use collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any `Map` implementation like `LinkedHashMap`, `HashMap` or `Hashtable`. They all store objects classified by keys which have their corresponding values.

You would declare this object as:

```
Map myMap = new Hashtable<String, File>();
```

Do whatever implementation for file input, you can then use the `put()` method like:

```
myMap.put("fileName", fileInstance);
```

You can remove a key, check for a key existance, check for a value existance, iterate over the keys and over values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections (i.e. List  (java.util.List). You can also store the collection of your object in the file  (I think use of serialize and de-serialize would increase your speed in reading and writing the data)